# index.js.erb not loading in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb

I'm having trouble with a index.js.erb which I've create but isn't execuing. I have the following in my controller:

```
def index
    @images = Image.order('id desc')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
end
```

And the following in my index.js.erb:

```
alert("it works")
```

If this helps as well I have the following in my coffee script file for this project:

```
ImagePoller =
poll: ->
    setTimeout @request, 5000

request: ->
    $.get($('#images').data('url'))

jQuery ->
if $('#images').length > 0
    ImagePoller.poll()
```

I can tell the js.erb file isn't load because I'm not seeing the alert? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you requesting with proper format at the end like `/images.js`? If you want Rails to render your 'index.js.erb', your url have to request with `.js` format.

Comment: Also check your server logs and make sure the poll isn't making an HTML request as opposed to a JS request.

Comment: @HungryCoder how do I make sure my url makes the .js request form?

Comment: @varatis thanks for the reponse, where do I find the server logs?

Comment: Don't you have rails server running on your console? It's the stuff that's getting printing out constantly onto your console

Comment: can you please paste codes that outputs the html markup with id `images`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making the ajax request, you're retrieving the url from '#images' element. All you need to make sure your URL contains proper format.

You can simply append the `.js` with the URL in your code:

```
request: ->
    $.get($('#images').data('url')) + '.js'
```

However, better way of doing is using rails helper methods. For example:

**haml**:

```
#images{:'data-url' => url_for(:action => 'index', :format => 'js')}
```

**ERB**:

```
<div id="images" data-url="<%=url_for(:action => 'index', :format => 'js')%>"></div>
```

The later case will already include the '.js' in the URL. so you won't need to append '.js' at the end that I've shown at beginning.